# Has shrank or has shrunk?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, irregular-forms

My sentence is:

> The total number of unique patients that fits this criterion has shrank from 10 to 5.

But I'm not sure if instead I should say `has shrunk`?

Comment: Even relatively illiterate native Anglophone know this one! So much so that they say *Who'd have **thunk** it?* as a facetious alternative to Present Perfect *Who would have **thought** it?* (but no-one *ever* says *Who'd have **thank** it?*)

Comment: The example sentence is incorrect: shrink (present tense), shrank (past tense), shrunk (past participle). The present perfect is formed using has/have + past participle.

Comment: You need to look up irregular verbs. They are in dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

"Has shr_nk" is a present perfect.

> The present perfect is formed from the present tense of the verb have and the past participle of a verb.
> [- British Council | Learn English](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect)

So your sentence should use "has shrunk".

See this [link](https://www.scribbr.com/verbs/past-participles/) for more about past participles.